# cron doesn't do anything

Tags: osx, cron

I tried making some crontabs, I created a file called `brewupdater` in my user folder, containing `0 */5 * * * ~/bin/brewupdate2`.

I then tried to run `cron ~/brewupdater` but it told me:

```
cron: can't open or create /var/run/cron.pid: Permission denied
```

So I tried `sudo cron ~/brewupdater`. But the script doesn't run, (it should do every 5th hour), because the files that should appear don't.

Comment: `cron(8)` typically runs as a daemon, and parses crontab files from a particular directory. Use `crontab(1)` to edit the contents of a crontab file for a user, e.g. `crontab < ~/brewupdater` to wipe out what may exist and add the brewupdate2 job, or before that `crontab -l` to see if there are already any jobs.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the command `crontab -e` as the user you want the script run as and put your `cron` schedule in that.